# Switch between multiple div elements on Gallery example

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, photo-gallery

I'm trying to build simple javascript/jquery gallery. I suppose this is a pretty specific question.

The logic is as follows: to make as many **div**s as array contains elements(**var sum**). These elements present image names. I realized that in first **for** loop(first **append** function adds image and the second one adds name list - to navigate between images). In second **for** loop I set initial value (show me first image) and it works.

I met with an obstacle when trying to assign function to clicked element from name list. Third **for** loop obviously works(since it's copy of the second one).
Is there any syntax error?

Code:

```
<div id="container"> //contains images
</div>

<div id="list"> //contains navigation numbers
</div>

<script>
    var array = ['0', '1', '2'];  //img names
    var sum = array.length;
    var currentId = 'a' + array[1];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
            $("#container").append("<img class='a' src='img/" + array[i] + ".jpg' id='a" + array[i] + "'>");
            $("#list").append("<a href='#a" + array[i] + "' onclick='checkButton()'>" + array[i] + "</a><br />");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
            var inactiveId = 'a' + array[i];
            if (currentId !== inactiveId) {
                document.getElementById(inactiveId).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        currentId1 = this.id;
        $(currentId1).click(function () {

            document.getElementById(currentId1).style.display = "block";

            for (var i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
                var inactiveId = 'a' + [i];
                if (inactiveId !== currentId1) {
                    document.getElementById(inactiveId).style.display = "none";
                }
            }

        })
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="container">
 <img id="dimg" src=""/>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="list">

</div>
<script>
 var images = [
     'http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/208/5695232-smile-pics.png',
     'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a5/0b/9f/a50b9f1bb631d41623510a779741ca67.jpg',
     'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c0/1e/7e/c01e7e0b36c7edba6a90887dc63ac49d--smiley-happy-smile-face.jpg'
    ];

 var sizes = {
  width: 100,
  height: 100
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {

  // Define the default size for all images
  $("#dimg").width(sizes.width).height(sizes.height);

  // Show the image names
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   let imgName = images[i].split("/");
   let anchor = $("<a href='#' lnk='" + images[i] + "'>" + imgName[imgName.length-1] + "</a><br/>");
   $("#list").append(anchor);

   // Click event
   anchor.on("click", function() {
    $("#dimg").attr("src", $(this).attr("lnk"));
   });
  }

  // Click to the first image name
  $("#list a:eq(1)").trigger("click");
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Mytzer! Based on your reply, I changed code block:

                `$(document).on("click", "#list > a", function () {
                var currentId1 = 'a' + $(this).attr("lnk");

                document.getElementById(currentId1).style.display = "block";

                for (var i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
                    var inactiveId = 'a' + [i];
                    if (inactiveId !== currentId1) {
                        document.getElementById(inactiveId).style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            })`

Answer (score 0):

The line `currentId1 = this.id;` seems to be the problem.

You are referencing `this.id` but you never declared it!

Edit:
Also see Kaddaths comment, he provided some more insight on what is also not working in your code!

Comment: there are other problems, feel free to edit your answer, because i won't add one: he is setting the click function on only one element (`$(currentId1)`) with using the global var `currentId1`. It means the function, as it is, cannot know which link was clicked (i think the OP thought that it would be `this`, but it's not even placed in the function). `this` should be passed as a function parameter or anything.